# A condition to determine if the parent container child elements contains of specific class and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what I've tried so far. But nothing of the three workaround works.

I've tried using hasClass and find but no luck to make it work.

HTML:

```
<div>Click me (I have a .cute class)
    <p class="cute"></p>
</div>

<div>Click me (I don't a .cute class)
    <p class="no-cute-class"></p>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").click(function(){
        //Looking for siblings if has class of cute
        if($(this).siblings().hasClass('cute')) {
             alert("Found cute class");
        } else {
             alert("Didn't found cute class");
        }

        //jQuery hasClass
        if($(this).hasClass('cute')) {
             alert("Found cute class");
        } else {
             alert("Didn't found cute class");
        }

        //Using jQuery find
        if($(this).find('.cute')) {
            alert("Found cute class");
        } else {
            alert("Didn't found cute class");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$("p .cute").click(function(){}`

Comment: you can't have `<div>` inside `<p>`. irrelevant HTML structure

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal for some reason I need the click to be on that.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes. Just an example :D

Comment: @Benjoe just use some inline element , and set it's `display` property to `block`, now you get block level element and semantically valid DOM too

Comment: @Towkir thanks. I revised the code but still nothing of my three solutions work.  code works like a charm. Seems like adding .length > 0 is the trick.

Comment: Try my answer @Benjoe

Comment: @ShubhamBaranwal yes. Removing > 0 seems to be working fine also. Thanks mate.

Comment: My Pleasure :) @Benjoe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you want to search whether class called `.cute` is inside your element. But you can not traverse from `p` to a `div`. better change as below and try.

You can use `length` to find out any related class is there.

```js
$("div").click(function(){
  if($(this).find('.cute').length > 0){
      alert('has class');
  }
  else{
      alert("no class");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click me (I have a .cute class)
    <span class="cute"></span>
</div>

<div>Click me (I don't a .cute class)
    <span class="no-cute-class"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome mate. Happy coding. Cheers! mark this as answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: As an additional info if($(this).find('.cute').length) seems to be working just fine also. Silentcoder.

Comment: @Benjoe I have noticed that too with @Towkir's answer. but actually, the `length` according to the jquery definition, it returns the number of elements in the jQuery object. but it is really interesting and thanks for pointing that too.

Comment: Wow. That's one good info! Maybe I'll stick with the length > 0 now XD

Answer (score 2):

You can't wrap `div` inside of `p` tag.

Because it renders in browser like below -

```
<p> <div> test </div> </p>
```

rendered in the DOM as:

```
<p> </p> <div> test </div> <p> </p>
```

You can also use `span` instead of `div` like below or try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb4wf1n2/5/)

HTML Code-

```
<div>
  <p>Click me (I have a .cute class)
    <span class="cute"></span>
  </p>

  <p>Click me (I don't a .cute class)
    <span class="no-cute-class"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

JS Code-

```
$("p").click(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.cute').length) {
    alert("Found Cute Class");
  } else {
    alert("Didn't found cute class");
  }
});
```

Comment: this is not an answer, this should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `hasClass` try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    if($(this).find("p").hasClass("cute")){
      alert("has cute");
    }
    else{
      alert("no class");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>Click me (I have a .cute class)
    <p class="cute"></p>
  </div>
  <div>Click me (I don't a .cute class)
    <p class="no-cute-class"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is also a good work around man. But in some cases we may want to change the <p> tag for example. Is there any way to make that dynamic using hasClass? This is useful if someone is looking for hasClass workaround. I've tested $(this).siblings().hasClass("cute") but it's not working.

Comment: Your `cute` class is inside the `div` so you cannot use `siblings`. You can use `children` instead.